# Tools::isSubmit() Prestashop not working

Tags: php, forms, form-submit, prestashop-1.6

I am new to prestashop and module development. I was practicing a module which allows users to submit comment on a product. But there is an issue with form submission. I think.

Below is the code I tried.(Only methods of interest)

**BulkyEdit.php**

```
public function install()
 {
    if (!parent::install() )
        return false;

        //Registering the hook.
        $this->registerHook('displayProductTabContent');
        return true;
}
public function hookDisplayProductTabContent($params)
{
   //Using hook displayProductTabContent.

   $this->processCommentPublish();
   return $this->display(__FILE__,'displayProductTabContent.tpl');
}
private function processCommentPublish()
{
   $stat = Tools::isSubmit('comment_submit_form');
   if($stat)
   {
     $stat = "submit success";
   }
   else $stat = "failure";
    Configuration::updateValue('BULKYEDIT_TESTVAL',$stat);
}
```

**displayProductTabContent.tpl**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Tell us your name" name="name"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">Your comment</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Tell us your name" name="comment"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="comment_submit_form" value="Publish"  />
    </div>
</form>
```

**$stat logs failure.**

**Edit : BULKYEDIT_TESTVAL logs Forms post failure**

```
if(isset($_POST['comment_submit_form']))
{
    Configuration::updateValue('BULKYEDIT_TESTVAL',$_POST); 
}
else{
    Configuration::updateValue('BULKYEDIT_TESTVAL','Forms post failure');
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: People still use PrestaShop? Check to ensure your $_POST requests are succeeding. It looks like the Tools class just checks to ensure the request `isset` https://github.com/pal/prestashop/blob/master/classes/Tools.php#L404

Comment: Thanks @djthoms for the comment, Yes I Just checked that also logs failure. But I can't figure out the reason. See Edit

Comment: Are you using something like XDebug? If so, I'd recommend setting a break point in the Tools class to see what's causing the failure. When in doubt, debug

Comment: @djthoms, Thanks dude. The first time I wrote code that was a bit different from this. Prestashop was using cache. As I disabled it everything is working fine now with dev mode on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Issues with the code.Everything works fine. Actually the code I wrote for the first time was different and I was using a wrong name in Tools::isSubmit('submit').But after I made changes prestashop kept using the cached files so I could not able to get the desired results according to my latest edits.

I then disabled cache and enabled Developer Mode following the instructions here.

http://blog.belvg.com/enabling-error-output-in-prestashop.html

And everything was working like a charm. So,  When developing. enable Developer mode on so you can see results of your latest edits.